# Recommended Test Suite management software

Tags: quality-center, testcase

I'm looking for a new test plan suite. 
I have used TestLink for years and this seems so outdated and slow.

Price does not matter, open source, paid, etc.

What I'm looking for is this:

- Fast (web based application?) For multiple users.
- Simple flow, create multiple test cases quickly without waiting for web load times (test link fails here).
- Easy metric reporting.
- Code coverage if possible.
- Possibly plugin for jira but not a dependency on jira.
- Bulk test execution
- Code Coverage
- Automation API (Integrate our automation successes into the manual plan)
- Modern, up to date, active community?

The above are only suggestions of what I'm looking for, if anything rings a bell please let me know.

Comment: Could you please update you question with more details on what exactly you need from software? Otherwise your question is too broad.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Viktor, 

I've updated my question.

Comment: Search results can be also helpful for you: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/search?q=test+suite+management

Comment: Which of these criteria are most important? Which are dealbreakers and which are nice-to-haves? This is a subjective question (it's an opinion piece, in a sense) but that's not entirely bad. We just have to remember [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) principles.

Answer (score 1):

If the price is not a matter, then [TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/tfs-overview-vs.aspx). However, it is not a TM tool, it is a full development pipeline, management, CI, everything tool.

I have been working with it for years and I found it a very good tool.

Comment: TFS combined with Microsoft Test Manager, I was very impressed when I first used it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [TestRail](http://www.gurock.com/testrail/) based on my experience. We are completely satisfied with our needs and expectation from Test Case Management system. And it also meets all your requirements (but without code coverage as far as I know).

Comment: Im trying to use the RetailMeNot sdk for testRails
https://github.com/RetailMeNot/TestRailSDK

Actual API documentation:
The http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/bindings-java

Would you happen to have any examples of your integration?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having the same issue you have with Testlink. I've tried to gather information on other tools in other departments of my company, and it seems that [Squash](http://www.squashtest.org/en) is a pretty good tool.

It is divided into two parts: SquashTM for manual testing and SquashTA for automatic testing, which seems to fit your needs.

I've played a bit with SquashTM on a local installation, and it seems to fit most of my personal needs, and i'm currently evaluating the cost to do a migration from Testlink to Squash. I'm not sure it will cover all your needs, but it can't be worse than Testlink in my opinion.

Last important thing, it's open source.